# Mule ESB Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: mule, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a flow that sends a push notification  via the google cloud messaging service. I have used the mule connector for gcm. However I cannot get it to work. My config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:gcm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/gcm" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/gcm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/gcm/1.0/mule-gcm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <gcm:config name="Google_Cloud_Messaging" apiKey="BLANK FOR POSTING" doc:name="Google Cloud Messaging"/>
    <flow name="GCMFlow1" doc:name="GCMFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9000" path="gcm" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <gcm:send-message config-ref="Google_Cloud_Messaging" doc:name="Google Cloud Messaging">
        <gcm:registration-ids>
            <gcm:registration-id>"APA91bGFeuXKNWuAkaFquqk0Dk45kkb-dBZdo_DLz8Ai8bLkZroQyBcDgw-SrA_B2aw2mnReO78rb9ivvn1Phu2x-eMWJmHmtLEOceC-hBGGQvbbpCvse2ZxvllJkYVP-G-jQrfOLOMF"</gcm:registration-id>
        </gcm:registration-ids>
    </gcm:send-message>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I get the following error :

```
Exception stack is:
1. Numeric value (5587416482739805649) out of range of int
 at [Source: org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream@1318bd3c; line: 1, column: 36] (org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException)
  org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser:1433 (null)
2. Failed to invoke sendMessage. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.gcm.processors.SendMessageMessageProcessor:236 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Numeric value (5587416482739805649) out of range of int
 at [Source: org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream@1318bd3c; line: 1, column: 36]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase.convertNumberToInt(JsonParserBase.java:829)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

My api key works as well as registration ID as I have tested them elsewhere.

update: Verbose debug output:

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke sendMessage. Message payload is of type: String
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : "1"
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Numeric value (8947223409733149407) out of range of int
 at [Source: org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream@669b824; line: 1, column: 36] (org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException)
  org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser:1433 (null)
2. Failed to invoke sendMessage. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.gcm.processors.SendMessageMessageProcessor:236 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Numeric value (8947223409733149407) out of range of int
 at [Source: org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream@669b824; line: 1, column: 36]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase.convertNumberToInt(JsonParserBase.java:829)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase.getIntValue(JsonParserBase.java:625)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseInteger(StdDeserializer.java:303)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:819)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:806)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1909)
    at org.mule.module.gcm.GcmConnector.sendMessage(GcmConnector.java:146)
    at org.mule.module.gcm.processors.SendMessageMessageProcessor$1.process(SendMessageMessageProcessor.java:225)
    at org.mule.module.gcm.adapters.GcmConnectorProcessAdapter$1.execute(GcmConnectorProcessAdapter.java:36)
    at org.mule.module.gcm.processors.SendMessageMessageProcessor.process(SendMessageMessageProcessor.java:211)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:101)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:112)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExe...
********************************************************************************
```

**NEW Updated FLOW:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:gcm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/gcm" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/gcm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/gcm/1.0/mule-gcm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <gcm:config name="Google_Cloud_Messaging" apiKey="my_key" doc:name="Google Cloud Messaging"/>
    <flow name="GCMFlow1" doc:name="GCMFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9001" path="gcm" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="APA91bGFeuXKNWuAkaFquqk0Dk45kkb-dBZdo_DLz8Ai8bLkZroQyBcDgw-SrA_B2aw2mnReO78rb9ivvn1Phu2x-eMWJmHmtLEOceC-hBGGQvbbpCvse2ZxvllJkYVP-G-jQrfOLOMF" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[ArrayList idRegID = new ArrayList();
 idRegID.add("APA91bGFeuXKNWuAkaFquqk0Dk45kkb-dBZdo_DLz8Ai8bLkZroQyBcDgw-SrA_B2aw2mnReO78rb9ivvn1Phu2x-eMWJmHmtLEOceC-hBGGQvbbpCvse2ZxvllJkYVP-G-jQrfOLOMF");
payload= idRegID;]]></expression-component>
        <gcm:send-message config-ref="Google_Cloud_Messaging" doc:name="Google Cloud Messaging">
            <gcm:registration-ids ref="#[payload]"/>
        </gcm:send-message>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: It already tells: *Numeric value (5587416482739805649) out of range of int*

Comment: Hi, where is it getting this value and what value is it. Is it something I am submitting to gcm or is it the return value from it??

Comment: Enable the verbose logging so we can see the full stack trace by adding the following JVM parameter to Mule: -Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an old version of the connector: the issue you're facing has been [fixed 7 months ago](https://github.com/mulesoft/google-connectors-suite/commit/ba2a4a9f48caa58fa46a318a542648cbca4cab88). You need to upgrade to a more recent version.

For the second issue you've added to your question: you do not need to create a list, use instead the XML elements:

```
<gcm:send-message ...
  <gcm:registration-ids>
    <gcm:registration-id>...</gcm:registration-id>
  </gcm:registration-ids>
  ...
```

PS. Your `gcm:registration-id` looks uber-strange. The `""` around it should probably go away.

Comment: Hi, thanks..fixed the "" issue. I did an update for the connector and it is the latest. I got another transformer error complaining about the payload needing to be a collection of type java.util.List. I created an  Arraylist with the regid hoping that would solve the problem. Unfortunately the original error with int out of range came back. not sure what I am doing wrong. I updated the original post with the new flow with mu tranformer included.

Comment: Mmmh, altering an existing question (issue with integer/long) with another issue is bad practice here at StackOverflow. Could you please accept this answer and create a new question with the List problem?

Comment: I am confused. The integer out of range issue was the original problem.  It still has not been solved? I added the extra flow to give more info in the progress I have made. Please advise if I am incorrect in my understanding.Thank you for your help

Comment: What version are you using? It should be 1.2.3. And yes, your second question is unrelated to the integer issue, but whatever, I've answered it too.

Comment: Downloaded latest code from github and updated plugin in studio. Mulestudio software update does nothing for gcm connector. Errors went away and now connecting to GCM properly. Thanks David for your assistance.

Comment: Awesome, glad to read that! Well, except the Studio update foobar part :$