# Mule ESB 3.6.0 Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: mule, google-cloud-messaging

I have a connector that works well on mule standalone 3.5.0:

[[Mule ESB Google Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303186/mule-esb-google-cloud-messaging) refs 21303186]

but unfortunately gives me the following strange error in the standalone version 3.6.0. Response should be json but we get an html.

```
        ERROR 2015-02-26 17:09:17,456 [[tcol_appsmobile2].Adapter_Notificaciones_Moviles.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
    ********************************************************************************
    Message               : Failed to deserialize to: class org.mule.module.gcm.model.GcmResponse from: der -->
      <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
          <div class="wrap" id="header-wrap">
            <div class="col-3 logo">
              <a href="/index.html">
                <img src="/assets/images/dac_logo.png"
                    srcset="/assets/images/dac_logo@2x.png 2x"
                    width="123" height="25" alt="Android Developers" />
              </a>
              <div class="btn-quicknav" id="btn-quicknav">
                <a href="#" class="arrow-inactive">Quicknav</a>
                <a href="#" class="arrow-active">Quicknav</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-x col-9">
                <li class="design">
                  <a href="/design/index.html"
                  zh-tw-lang="è¨­è¨"
                  zh-cn-lang="è®¾è®¡"
...



  <script src="https://developer.android.com/ytblogger_lists_unified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/jd_lists_unified.js?v=8" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/jd_extras.js?v=9" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/jd_collections.js?v=9" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/jd_tag_helpers.js?v=5" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>




Code                  : MULE_ERROR-10999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@207fe31; line: 1, column: 2] (org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException)
  org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser:1433 (null)
2. Failed to deserialize to: class org.mule.module.gcm.model.GcmResponse from: der -->
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

That connector has not been mantained for some time so it is possible it is not compatible with 3.6.0.

You could fork it and update to 3.6.0 if you want from https://github.com/mulesoft/google-cloud-messaging-connector or send a pull request with the changes